# Implementation of Debug for NdArray causes subtraction underflow error

Tags: rust, multidimensional-array, printing

Suppose I have a general `NdArray<T, N>` which is guaranteed to be rectangular and have a shape of `[usize; N]` - e.g. `[2, 2]` for a square matrix, or `[3]` for a column vector. I would like to pretty-print that NdArray in the same way NumPy prints its n-dimensional arrays. This is what I have so far (code mostly ported from [tinynumpy](https://github.com/almarklein/tinynumpy)):

```rust
use core::fmt::Debug;
use std::cmp::{min, max};
use std::fmt;

pub struct NdArray<T: Clone, const N: usize> {
    pub shape: [usize; N],
    pub data: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T: Clone, const N: usize> NdArray<T, N> {
    pub fn from(array: Vec<T>, shape: [usize; N]) -> Self {
        NdArray { shape, data: array }
    }
}

fn _display_inner<T: Clone + Debug, const N: usize>(f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>, array: &NdArray<T, N>, axis: usize, offset: usize) -> std::fmt::Result {
    let axisindent = min(2, max(0, array.shape.len() - axis -1));
    if axis < array.shape.len() {
        f.write_str("[")?;
        for (k_index, k) in (0..array.shape[axis]).into_iter().enumerate() {
            if k_index > 0 {
                for _ in 0..axisindent {
                    f.write_str("\n       ")?;
                    for _ in 0..axis {
                        f.write_str(" ")?;
                    }
                }
            }
            let offset_ = offset + k;
            _display_inner(f, array, axis + 1, offset_)?;
            if k_index < &array.shape[axis] - 1 {
                f.write_str(", ")?;
            }
        }
    } else {
        f.write_str(format!("{:?}", array.data[offset]).as_str())?;
    }
    Ok(())
}

impl<T: Clone, const N: usize> fmt::Debug for NdArray<T, N> 
where T: Debug
{ 
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self.shape.len() {
            0 => write!(f, "NdArray([])"),
            1 => write!(f, "NdArray({:?}, shape={:?})", self.data, self.shape),
            _ => _display_inner(f, &self, 0, 0)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = NdArray::from(vec![1., 2., 3., 4.], [2, 2]);
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

For reference, this is the original unported Python code:

```py
def print_nested_list(flat_array, shape):
    def _repr_r(s, axis, offset):
            axisindent = min(2, max(0, (len(shape) - axis - 1)))
            if axis < len(shape):
                s += '['
                for k_index, k in enumerate(range(shape[axis])):
                    if k_index > 0:
                        s += ('\n       ' + ' ' * axis)  * axisindent
                    offset_ = offset + k
                    s = _repr_r(s, axis+1, offset_)
                    if k_index < shape[axis] - 1:
                        s += ', '
                s += ']'
            else:
                r = repr(flat_array)[offset])
                if '.' in r:
                    r = ' ' + r
                    if r.endswith('.0'):
                        r = r[:-1]
                s += r
            return s
    s = _repr_r('', 0, 0)
    print(f"array({s})")
```

However, this results in:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to subtract with overflow', src/main.rs:17:36
```

This is likely because usize doesn't support negative numbers, unlike the original Python code from tinynumpy, which causes the code to panic if axis < 1.

Is there a better way at implementing `Debug`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your problem:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = sub1(0);
}
fn saturating_sub1(a: usize) -> usize {
    std::cmp::max(0, a - 1);
}
```

but a `usize` can't go below 0 because it is ***u***nsigned, so the second parameter to `max` is always `>= 0` as you've noticed Rust saves you from getting `usize::MAX` by panicing instead of silently wrapping in debug mode. Instead you can use `saturating_sub` to achieve the same saturating behaviour:

```rust
fn saturating_sub1(a: usize) -> usize {
    a.saturating_sub(1)
}
```